# Is RDP service visible externally / publicly when hidden behind a firewall?

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-access, remote-desktop, rdp

This may be a simple enough answer but I'm hoping someone with the knowledge can answer.

We are using SonicWall firewall for SSLVPN and using firewall rules restricting access to RDP for SSLVPN users only, all other traffic to the RDP service is rejected.

I want to know if this RDP service and port are visible externally outside of the VPN. So if someone were to for example do a scan using Nmap or Shodan would it be visible?

Comment: You can check your IP on Shodan by entering your IP into the search box. Shodan continuously scans the entire Internet and when you do a search you're doing a lookup in the database of information it's already collected (i.e. using Shodan doesn't make you show up on Shodan). If you have RDP exposed you will see port 3389 open.

Answer (score 1):

I would go off the VPN/office network and just run an nmap scan to confirm this. You could spin up an EC2 instance or test it from home using `nmap -sT -sU -p 3389 <IP>`. That nmap scan is checking UDP (-sU) and TCP CONNECT (-sT) on port (-p) 3389. In my experience, it's best to audit your firewall rules yourself using proven tools. You can do this with netcat/nc as well, you don't actually need nmap.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to another network and test or use an online service like https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to see what ports are open.